# How do I make it so that I can have

Tags: php

How do I make it so i can have commas / and brakes in my php code for the reply. When I try to add it I get my reply cannot be added or w.e. error, and When I press enter to break to the next line It just makes a space. 
Here is my code:

```
    <?php 

    if($_SESSION['signed_in'])  
    { echo '
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="header">
        <h3>Post Reply</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container_oro2">

    <div class="cpadding">
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[color=][/color]" value="Color"  />
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[size=11px][/size]" value="Size" />
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[b][/b]" value="Bold" />
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[i][/i]" value="Italic" />
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[u][/u]" value="Underline" />
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[img][/img]" value="Image" />
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[url=http://][/url]" value="URL" />
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[center][/center]" value="Center" />
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[quote=][/quote]" value="Quote" />
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[spoiler][/spoiler]" value="Spoiler" />
    <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[/youtube]" value="YouTube Video" />
    </div>

    <br/>   <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="center">
            <textarea id="form" name="reply-content" cols="70" rows="8"> </textarea>
            <br/><input type="submit" name="add_submit" value="Submit Post" />       </div>
    </form>


 </div>';
     }  
     else  
     {  
                echo '<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="header">
        <h3>Post Reply</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container_oro2">


    <div class="center"><B>You must <a href="/index.php?area=login">Login</a> or <a  href="/index.php?area=register">create an account</a> to 

    post.</B></div>


    </div>


                ';  
    } 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    {

    echo '';
    }
    else
    {

    if(!$_SESSION['signed_in'])
    {
        echo 'You must be signed in to post a reply.';
    }
    else
    {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    posts(post_content,
                          post_date,
                          post_topic,
                          post_by) 
                VALUES ('" . $_POST['reply-content'] . "',
                        NOW(),
                        " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) .  ",
                        " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ")";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if(!$result)
        {
            echo 'Your reply has not been saved, please try again later.';
        }
        else
        { $Max_id = $rows['reply']+1;$id=($_GET['id']);
    header( 'Location: /index.php?area=topic&id=' . htmlentities($_GET['id']) . '' ) ;
            echo 'Your reply has been saved, check out <a href="">the topic</a>.';
    $sql2 = "UPDATE $topics SET reply='$Max_id' WHERE id='$id'"; $result2=mysql_query($sql2);}
    }
    } 
     ?>
```

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you please explain your problem a bit more?  Just pasting code and saying "fix this" isn't very well received here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what your trying to do, but I'd wouldn't be echoing all that HTML using PHP - rather using closed tags:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['signed_in']) { ?>

HTML

<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use all that code in the same file. However in answer to your question you can remove the echo statements and just use blocks of HTML. eg:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['signed_in']){ ?>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="header">
        <h3>Post Reply</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container_oro2">
        <div class="cpadding">
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[color=][/color]" value="Color"  />
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[size=11px][/size]" value="Size" />
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[b][/b]" value="Bold" />
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[i][/i]" value="Italic" />
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[u][/u]" value="Underline" />
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[img][/img]" value="Image" />
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[url=http://][/url]" value="URL" />
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[center][/center]" value="Center" />
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[quote=][/quote]" value="Quote" />
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[spoiler][/spoiler]" value="Spoiler" />
            <input type="button" class="bbbutton light" title="[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[/youtube]" value="YouTube Video" />
        </div>

        <br/>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="center">
                <textarea id="form" name="reply-content" cols="70" rows="8"> </textarea>
                <br/><input type="submit" name="add_submit" value="Submit Post" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="header">
        <h3>Post Reply</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container_oro2">
        <div class="center"><B>You must <a href="/index.php?area=login">Login</a> or <a  href="/index.php?area=register">create an account</a> to post.</B></div>
    </div>
<?php } 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') { ?>

<?php } else {
    if(!$_SESSION['signed_in']){
        echo 'You must be signed in to post a reply.';
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    posts(post_content,
                          post_date,
                          post_topic,
                          post_by) 
                VALUES ('{$_POST['reply-content']}',
                        NOW(),
                        " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . ",
                        '{$_SESSION['user_id']}')";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if(!$result) {
            echo 'Your reply has not been saved, please try again later.';
        } else {
            $Max_id = $rows['reply']+1;$id=($_GET['id']);

            echo 'Your reply has been saved, check out <a href="">the topic</a>.';
            $sql2 = "UPDATE $topics SET reply='$Max_id' WHERE id='$id'"; $result2=mysql_query($sql2);}
            header('Location: /index.php?area=topic&id=' . htmlentities($_GET['id'])) ;
        }
    } 
?>
```